# How i can filter, with Eloquent, either in tables and join tables at the same time?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have two tables, `product_template` and `shorttitles`.

A product can have multiple shorttitles, depending on language
A product has a primary title (called `mmac_ebay_titolo`), and a shorttitle has a name, that is the title in different language.

***My goal*** is to filter, depending on post input, the shorttitles title and the product_template title with the string posted.

if no filter string is passed, all works fine.

The `shorttitles` model has this relation:

```php
public function prodotto()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

The `product_template` model has this relation:

```php
public function shorttitle()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ShortTitle', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

But I'm stuck with the code below:

```php
$m = self::MODEL;
$query = $m::select("*");

$data["data"] = $query
 ->with(["prodotto" => function ($q) use ($params) {
            $q->select("id", "name", "mmac_ebay_titolo")
              ->where("name", "like", "%" . $params["search"] . "%");
       }]
)->where("lang_id", "=", 1)
 ->offset($start)
 ->limit($limit)
 ->orderBy("id", "asc")
 ->get();
```

This query returns all shorttitles... with "prodotto" = null if the subquery doesn't match the where clause. Why?

After this, I would filter the main shorttitles table with this:

```php
$m = self::MODEL;
$query = $m::select("*");

$data["data"] = $query
 ->with(["prodotto" => function ($q) use ($params) {
            $q->select("id", "name", "mmac_ebay_titolo")
              ->where("mmac_ebay_titolo", "like", "%" . $params["search"] . "%");
       }]
)->where("lang_id", "=", 1)
 ->where("name", "like", "%" . $params["search"] . "%")
 ->offset($start)
 ->limit($limit)
 ->orderBy("id", "asc")
 ->get();
```

I want to reproduce this query:

```sql
Select
    s.name,
    p.name,
    p.mmac_ebay_titolo
From
    mmac_brx_ebay_shorttitles s Inner Join
    product_template p On s.product_id = p.id
where lang_id = 1
and
(
  s.name like '%PIGNONE%'
  or
  p.name  like '%PIGNONE%'
  or
  p.mmac_ebay_titolo like '%PIGNONE%'
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
$products = $query->join('product_template','mmac_brx_ebay_shorttitles.product_id','=','product_template.id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
       $query->Where('mmac_brx_ebay_shorttitles.name','like','%PIGNONE%')
             ->orWhere('product_template.name','like','%PIGNONE%')
             ->orWhere('product_template.mmac_ebay_titolo','like','%PIGNONE%');
    })->where('your_table_name.lang_id',1)
    ->select('mmac_brx_ebay_shortitles.name','product_template.name','product_template.mmac_ebay_titolo')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it is the same of raw query... is it possible to use a pure eloquent approach?

Comment: https://daylerees.com/code-happy-eloquent-orm/

Check this URL you can find "Eager Loading" which will help you on this